# 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems' is persistent even after using 2to3.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ipython

I am working with this notebook https://github.com/mhamilton723/TimeSeriesRegressor/blob/master/Time%20Series%20Estimator%20Demo.ipynb

when I execute In [8] the following exception shows up. The rest of the blocks execute fine. The original TimeSeriesEstimator file had params.iteritems(), which I subsequently changed to params.items(). 2to3.py then changed it to the current form. However, the error persists after all these changes

```
> -----------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-6fe5ed989337> in <module>()
     16 cv = cascade_cv(len(X_train), n_folds=5)
     17 grid = GridSearchCV(tsr, param_grid, cv=cv)
---> 18 grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
     19 pred_train_3 = grid.predict(X_train)  # outputs a numpy array of length: len(X_train)-n_prev
     20 pred_test_3 = grid.predict(X_test)

C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\grid_search.py in fit(self, X, y)
    802 
    803         """
--> 804         return self._fit(X, y, ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
    805 
    806 

C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\grid_search.py in _fit(self, X, y, parameter_iterable)
    551                                     self.fit_params, return_parameters=True,
    552                                     error_score=self.error_score)
--> 553                 for parameters in parameter_iterable
    554                 for train, test in cv)
    555 

C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    798             # was dispatched. In particular this covers the edge
    799             # case of Parallel used with an exhausted iterator.
--> 800             while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
    801                 self._iterating = True
    802             else:

C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    656                 return False
    657             else:
--> 658                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    659                 return True
    660 

C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    564 
    565         if self._pool is None:
--> 566             job = ImmediateComputeBatch(batch)
    567             self._jobs.append(job)
    568             self.n_dispatched_batches += 1

C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in __init__(self, batch)
    178         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    179         # arguments in memory
--> 180         self.results = batch()
    181 
    182     def get(self):

C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self)
     70 
     71     def __call__(self):
---> 72         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
     73 
     74     def __len__(self):

C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     70 
     71     def __call__(self):
---> 72         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
     73 
     74     def __len__(self):

C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py in _fit_and_score(estimator, X, y, scorer, train, test, verbose, parameters, fit_params, return_train_score, return_parameters, error_score)
   1518 
   1519     if parameters is not None:
-> 1520         estimator.set_params(**parameters)
   1521 
   1522     start_time = time.time()

C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Python\TimeSeriesRegressor-master\TimeSeriesRegressor-master\TimeSeriesEstimator.py in set_params(self, **params)
     18 
     19     def set_params(self, **params):
---> 20         for param, value in list(params.items()):
     21             if param in self.get_params():
     22                 super(TimeSeriesEstimator, self).set_params(**{param: value})

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Comment: Did you try removing the compiled bytecode files?

Comment: I am new to python..could you please tell me how to remove bytecode files

Comment: *nix: `find -name '*.pyc' -delete` — windows: `del /s *.pyc`

Comment: Thanks. Removed the bytecode files. Error still persists

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham hope you could help

Comment: You may try removing `*.pyo` as well, they are less common, they happen when byte-compiling with `-O` option but they have the same effect as `pyc` file.

Comment: thanks. tried that as well...there were no .pyo files